# A more flexible sort

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to sort a list of customer names and it works however as you can see below it sorts the list that now goes from A2 through A47. I'm worried that when the size of the list grows or contracts my macro will not work properly. How can I adjust this so that my sort macro works in any list running down column A. Thank you.

```
Sub ByCustomerName()
'
' ByCustomerName Macro
' Sorts by Customer Name
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("My Customers").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("My Customers").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A47"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("My Customers").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B47")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set your range rather than hard-coding it\

Change `.SetRange Range("A1:B47")`

---

At the top of the code try

```
Dim sortRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set sortRange = Range("A1:B" & lastRow)
```

Then `.SetRange sortRange`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))`

This should select all non-empty rows starting with A1.